# Close new untitled document when opening a saved document

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdocument

When I open TextEdit, it opens a new untitled document which is closed as soon as I open a saved document from disk. But even if one would think that this is standard behavior in a document-based app in Cocoa, this doesn't seem to be the case. In my app the untitled document stays open even when I open another document. How to avoid this?

Comment: TextEdit is sample code, you can see how it is done. Browse DocumentController.m.

Comment: That's right, I completely forgot. Looking at the code it seems like one has to check for an AppleEvent when opening an untitled document, which already sounds too complicated to me, so I'll let someone else figure out an easier way of doing this (if it exists, which I doubt). But thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but as I could not find a solution anywhere, here I am. The TextEdit example can be simplified, my Swift solution is: (Objc version below)

- if your app does not already include an `NSDocumentController` subclass, create one named `DocumentController`
  and instantiate it in `applicationWillFinishLaunching` (see [here](https://talk.objc.io/episodes/S01E145-setting-up-a-document-based-app)):

```
    func applicationWillFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
        _ = DocumentController()
    }
```

- make sure your `Document` class has a Boolean property to indicate it is a transient document:

```
   var isTransient = false
```

- then override the following `NSDocumentController` functions as follows.
- In `openUntitledDocumentAndDisplay` we check if the new untitled document is the only one that is open. If yes, we look at the `currentAppleEvent` to see if the app is opening or reopening. If yes, our new 'Untitled' document is a transient document and should be closed when another document is opened. So we set `isTransient` to true.
- In `openDocument`, before we open the document, first we check if there is currently only 1 document open and see if it is marked as transient. If true, we close it.

```
import Cocoa

class DocumentController : NSDocumentController {
    override func openUntitledDocumentAndDisplay(_ displayDocument: Bool) throws -> NSDocument {
        let document = try super.openUntitledDocumentAndDisplay(displayDocument) as! Document
        
        if documents.count == 1 {
            if let eventDescriptor = NSAppleEventManager.shared().currentAppleEvent {
                let eventID = eventDescriptor.eventID
                document.isTransient = (eventID == kAEReopenApplication || eventID == kAEOpenApplication) && (eventDescriptor.eventClass == kCoreEventClass)
            }
            
        }
        return document
    }

    override func openDocument(withContentsOf url: URL, display displayDocument: Bool) async throws -> (NSDocument, Bool) {
        if documents.count == 1 {
            let firstDoc = documents.first as! Document
            
            if firstDoc.isTransient {
                firstDoc.close()
            }
        }
        
        return try await super.openDocument(withContentsOf: url, display: displayDocument)
    }
}
```

Objc solution:

```
- (id)openUntitledDocumentAndDisplay:(BOOL)displayDocument error:(NSError **)outError {
    Document *doc = [super openUntitledDocumentAndDisplay:displayDocument error:outError];
    
    if (!doc) return nil;
    
    if (self.documents.count == 1) {
        NSAppleEventDescriptor *evtDesc = NSAppleEventManager.sharedAppleEventManager.currentAppleEvent;
        AEEventID evtID = evtDesc.eventID;
        
        if (evtDesc && (evtID == kAEReopenApplication || evtID == kAEOpenApplication) && [evtDesc eventClass] == kCoreEventClass) {
            doc.isTransient = YES;
        }
    }
    
    return doc;
}

- (id)openDocumentWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)absoluteURL display:(BOOL)displayDocument error:(NSError **)outError {
    if (self.documents.count == 1) {

        Document *firstDoc = (Document *)self.documents[0];
        if (firstDoc.isTransient) {
            [firstDoc close];
        }

        return [super openDocumentWithContentsOfURL:absoluteURL display: displayDocument error:outError];
    }
}
```

Bonus tip: if the 'Untitled' transient document is being changed by the user, you probably don't want it to close automatically anymore. In that case Set `isTransient` to `false` when the document change count is modified.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just noticed that TextEdit doesn't seem to create an untitled document anymore, it just shows the open panel. Do you see the same behaviour? Even when creating an untitled document from the open panel and then opening another document, the untitled document stays open.

Comment: @Nickkk yes they changed TextEdits behaviour but this can be fixed with: `defaults write com.apple.TextEdit NSShowAppCentricOpenPanelInsteadOfUntitledFile -bool false`

Comment: What you are missing is checking whether the untitled document has been edited, in which case it should not be closed. TextEdit apparently simply sets `isTransient = false` inside `updateChangeCount(_:)`: [see source code here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/TextEdit/Listings/Document_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011741-Document_m-DontLinkElementID_12). But then, they also do a lot of other stuff: they don't simply close the untitled document but replace its contents with the opened document, and make a lot of checks to ensure that window cascading still works, etc.

Comment: So all in all, it's too much code and too complex housekeeping for such a simple feature, in my opinion. Which is why I'm leaving it out of my app. If Apple would take all feedback seriously, or thought that this kind of behaviour should be adopted by third-party apps, they would have offered a simpler way of doing this, without requiring us to dive deep into their sample code, which does things that I personally would never even dream about.